# Non-autoblocking MessageBoxes in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Anyone know a messageBox in .NET that doesn't block the thread that created it untill it's closed ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default `MessageBox` which you are using through `System.Windows.Forms` namespace will always be Modal (i.e., Blocking). If you want to have a Modeless message box, you should create your own `WindowsForm` that looks like a `MessageBox`.

You will then display this Form as follows:

```
// C#
//Display frmAbout as a modeless dialog
Form f= new Form();
f.Show();
```

Comment: Can i pass to .Show a string so i can use a quick "find and replace" ( i have a lot of messageBoxes ) ?

Comment: In your Form class, add a string member and set it through constructor. And on your FormLoad, show this string on the form as static text.

Answer (score 30):

```
private void ShowMessageBox(string text, string caption)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() => MyMessageBox(text, caption));
    t.Start();
}

private void MyMessageBox(object text, object caption)
{
    MessageBox.Show((string)text, (string)caption);
}
```

You can call `ShowMessageBox()` with your text and caption. This is just a simple sample, you can add buttons or icons owner or other arguments you want.

Answer (score 18):

You can simplify these other answers down to one line of code

```
new Thread(() => System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(text)).Start();
```

Answer (score 15):

Probably the simplest is:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => MessageBox.Show(text));
t.Start();
```