# Pop-up form freezes background form

Tags: windows, vb.net

I have a windows for application in Vb.Net.

It pop-up a warning screen and in order to close this messagebox we have to click "OK" button. When this warning popups my background form freezes.

Both forms are in timer.

```
If dServer_Time > dEndtime AndAlso Not mssg Then
    a = True
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
    Me.Show()
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized

    MessageBox.Show("Message Text", "Header", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, CType(262144, MessageBoxOptions))
End If
```

I want by background form to run when messagebox appears.

Comment: That's not c#, that's VB.NET. Are you sure you know what you are doing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-autoblocking MessageBoxes in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245138/non-autoblocking-messageboxes-in-c-sharp)

Comment: sorry about that.

Comment: `MessageBox` is designed to work like that. If you don't want the background form to freeze, you need to create another form window.

Comment: You should learn what a modal dialogue is.  Also, to say that a form is "in a timer" is nonsensical.